# How to Setup Spark on Windows 10, Step by Step

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I was trying setup spark on windows 10, found lot of good solutions on the stack overflow. So, i am trying to combine all the solutions and create standardized steps of installation

Comment: Install vm mapr. Far better.

Answer (score 6):

For installation first you need to download following:

1. JAVA JDK - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. SBT and Scala -     https://www.scala-lang.org/download/
3. Winutils.exe - https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1
4. Spark - https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

After downloading is completed

**Installing and setting up java**

When java installation completed, then:

1. Create folder BigData under C:\
2. Copy **“Java”** folder from **"C:\Program Files\"**  -->  **"C:\"**
3. Then create Environment Variables with name “JAVA_HOME”.

Advance System Settings --> Environment Variables --> Click on New button

Variable Name: JAVA_HOME

Variable Value: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

4. Add **bin** to **"Path"**, go to Advance System Settings-->Environment Variables-->Click on Path --> Click on new --> Write

**%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

**Installing and setting up sbt and scala**

Install sbt and scala, under the folder C:\Bigdata, after installation is done with sbt and scala

1. Create Environment Variable with name “SCALA_HOME”.

Advance System Settings --> Environment Variables --> Click on New button

Variable Name: SCALA_HOME

Variable Value: C:\BigData\scala

2. Add **bin** to **"Path"**, go to Advance System Settings-->Environment Variables-->Click on Path --> Click on new --> Write,

   **%SCALA_HOME%\bin**

**Setting up Hadoop libraries for windows**

1. Download zip from the mentioned git link above, then unzip the downloaded file from git and then, copy the **winutils.exe** from the **“winutils-master\hadoop-2.7.1\bin”** folder to C:\Bigdata\hadoop\bin
2. Create Environment Variable with name "HADOOP_HOME", Advance Settings --> Environment Variables --> Click on New

Variable Name: HADOOP_HOME

Variable Value: C:\BigData\hadoop

3. Add **bin** to **"Path"**, go to Advance Settings --> Environment Variables --> Click on Path--> Click on New , and write

**%HADOOP_HOME%\bin**

**Installing and setting up spark**

Extract the downloaded package of spark and then copy the folder to C:\Bigdata\, and rename the copied folder to "spark".

1. Create Environment Variable with name "SPARK_HOME",

Advance Settings --> Environment Variables --> Click on New -->

Variable Name : SPARK_HOME

Variable Value: C:\BigData\spark

2. Add **bin** to **Path**, Advance Settings --> Environment Variables --> Click on Path --> Click on New --> Write

**%SPARK_HOME%\bin**

3. Now create /tmp/hive directory under C:\, and set the permissions by following commands:

open cmd prompt:

**mkdir c:\tmp**

**mkdir c:\tmp\hive**

**winutils chmod 777 /tmp/hive**

Now, setup is completed.

goto cmd prompt and type "spark-shell", to run the spark.

**Some things that I faced, and it was giving issue:**

1. Your Computer Name should not contain underscore, that was giving me error.
2. Java JDK need to be installed and version should be Java 1.8.0_181
3. Multiple Java version configured, and that was giving me issue, there should be only one java version need to be configure.